# Lua: Taking a Recursive Action into a Single One

Tags: recursion, lua

I'm using Lua to create a "plug-in" for a Linux-based operating system.  This program contains a C function that currently is a recursive one (not intended to be but is).  At this moment, each time the function is called it provides the result 4-5 times.

I'd like to ask a question concerning recursive function(s) and their results.  Is it possible to take the multiple (same) results of a recursive function and only use one of the set(s) of results?

Example: (I'm going to state "OS function" to help point out what is already coded into the operating system I'm integrating Lua into)

```
function abc123() -- OS function based in the OS
    local names = os_Names() -- OS function
    local index, var = os_Rows() -- OS function to pull vars from file
    for k,v in pairs(names) do
        index2, var2 = os_Rows(k) -- OS function to pull vars from file
        if var2 ~= var then
            os_Rows(k,var2,var) -- RECURSIVE OS function
            cnt = 1
            while cnt <= 4 do
                 data_tbl = file_info(x,y,z) -- personal function to grab info and return a table
                 info_tbl[data_tbl.id]=data_tbl
                 loop_erase(info_tbl) -- my thoughts if possible
                 cnt = cnt + 1
            end
        end
    end
end

function loop_erase(entry) -- can something like this work????
    local order = {[1]="",[2]="",[3]="",[4]=""}
    for k,v in ipairs(entry) do
        for key,value in ipairs(order) do
            if key == k then
                value = v
            end
        end
    end
end
```

There are four slave devices, and their names are maintained in the `os_Names` function.  When a particular file is selected on any of the four slaves, the `os_Rows` function is called and sets `index, var` to the location and name of the file.  At this point, the `for` loop checks the other devices for what is currently set on them.  If it does not match `index, var` then it selects the `var` file on that slave device.

Right now, everything is working as it should up to the point where `if var2 ~= var`.  If the variables don't match in all four `names`, then it performs the `os_Rows(k,var2,var)` OS function which is the cause of the problem.  At this point, the proper function is performed but it does it four times.  This occurring over each of the four files - four times is an exponential problem!  So this is the recursive action I'm trying to stop.  Ultimately, all of this information is being transmitted to outside slave devices (via ethernet) that I'm afraid will cause communication issues.

Now I know that my approach to this is probably very drawn out and can be shortened by an expert programmer.  But right now, the `function abc123()` is returning four results (which is good) four times in a row (which is bad).  My thoughts are that I would try to put them into a table and if the keys of that table matched, then it would simply overwrite them.

a) I'm unsure if it is even possible to do this since my attempts so far haven't worked

b) If it is possible, I thought that the `function loop_erase` would be the way to go.

I'm thinking that this isn't possible since each time the recursive function occurs, it is still calling upon the other functions it links to.  I've been trying different methods and no go.

Comment: That function is looping four times for each name returned by `OS_Names` is that the "recursive" problem you are having?

Comment: @EtanReisner I've updated my question to answer yours.  I believe the explanation immediately after my code should convey my situation in more detail.  Thanks Etan!

Comment: What do the `os_Names` and `os_Rows` functions do? Are you trying to only run the inner block of code when *all four* names don't match? That is when `var2 ~= var` has failed for *every* name?

Comment: @EtanReisner I've updated my initial post to reflect your question, Etan.  You can find it immediately after the code.  Thanks again for your question(s)